# ES2020 optional chaining: what's the difference between a?.().b and a()?.b and a?.()?.b

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

Suppose we have this object:

```
let obj = {};
```

What exactly each of these expressions do?

- `obj.a?.().b`
- `obj.a()?.b`
- `obj.a?.()?.b`

Comment: This will just give you undefined. Do you have a proper example with the defined values for this particular scenario?

Comment: @Claies Surprisingly, `a?.()` is not a syntax error.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've already read the docs. I still don't understand the difference between them.

Comment: @MonsterCat Just reading won't help, apply it a few times and you'll get the hang of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `obj.a?.().b`

1. Dereference `obj` directly.
2. Dereference `obj.a` in a null-safe way - **it will stop at this point if the property is not there, it is `undefined` or `null`. If that happens the result of evaluating the expression will be `undefined`**.
3. Execute that value directly.
4. Receive the return result and continue.
5. Get the property `b` from the result directly.

[image: Flowchart for the above process]

```js
const tryIt = obj => {
  console.log("------start------");

  console.log("trying with", obj );

  try {
    console.log( "result", obj.a?.().b );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("problem", e.message);
  }

  console.log("-------end-------");
}

tryIt( null );                 // ERROR
tryIt( {} );                   // undefined
tryIt( { a: undefined } );     // undefined
tryIt( { a: null } );          // undefined
tryIt( { a: false } );         // ERROR
tryIt( { a: "hello" } );       // ERROR
tryIt( { a: function() {} } ); // ERROR
tryIt( {                       // ERROR
  a: function() {
    return null; 
  }
});
tryIt( {                       // 42
  a: function() {
    return { b: 42 };
  }
});
```

## `obj.a()?.b`

1. Dereference `obj` directly.
2. Dereference `obj.a` directly.
3. Executing that value directly.
4. Handle the value in a null-safe way - **it will stop at this point if the return value is `null` or `undefined`. If that happens the result of evaluating the expression will be `undefined`**.
5. Get the property `b` from the result directly.

[image: Flowchart for the above process]

```js
const tryIt = obj => {
  console.log("------start------");

  console.log("trying with", obj );

  try {
    console.log( "result", obj.a()?.b );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("problem", e.message);
  }

  console.log("-------end-------");
}


tryIt( null );                 // ERROR
tryIt( {} );                   // ERROR
tryIt( { a: undefined } );     // ERROR
tryIt( { a: null } );          // ERROR
tryIt( { a: false } );         // ERROR
tryIt( { a: "hello" } );       // ERROR
tryIt( { a: function() {} } ); // undefined
tryIt( {                       // undefined
  a: function() {
    return null; 
  }
});
tryIt( {                       // 42
  a: function() {
    return { b: 42 };
  }
});
```

## `obj.a?.()?.b`

1. Dereference `obj` directly.
2. Dereference `obj.a` in a null-safe way - **it will stop at this point if the property is not there, it is `undefined` or `null`. If that happens the result of evaluating the expression will be `undefined`**.
3. Executing that value directly.
4. Handle the value in a null-safe way - **it will stop at this point if the return value is `null` or `undefined`. If that happens the result of evaluating the expression will be `undefined`**.
5. Get the property `b` from the result directly.

[image]

```js
const tryIt = obj => {
  console.log("------start------");

  console.log("trying with", obj );

  try {
    console.log( "result", obj.a?.()?.b );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("problem", e.message);
  }

  console.log("-------end-------");
}


tryIt( null );                 // ERROR
tryIt( {} );                   // undefined
tryIt( { a: undefined } );     // undefined
tryIt( { a: null } );          // undefined
tryIt( { a: false } );         // ERROR
tryIt( { a: "hello" } );       // ERROR
tryIt( { a: function() {} } ); // undefined
tryIt( {                       // undefined
  a: function() {
    return null; 
  }
});
tryIt( {                       // 42
  a: function() {
    return { b: 42 };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`obj.a?.().b` - If `obj.a` is `null` or `undefined` then the expression is `undefined` otherwise the expression evaluates to `obj.a().b`.

`obj.a()?.b` - If `obj.a()` is `null` or `undefined` then the expression is `undefined` otherwise the expression evaluates to `obj.a().b`

`obj.a?.()?.b` if `obj.a` or `obj.a()` is `null` or `undefined` then the expression is `undefined` otherwise the expression evaluates to `obj.a().b`.

Read more about optional chaining [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Why does `obj.a()?.b` throw an error? shouldn't it evaluate to `undefined`?

Comment: @MonsterCat `obj.a` is not a function. `a` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) can be used in three locations:

1. In place of the dot operator for property access (`obj?.a`)
2. Immediately before the bracket syntax for property access (`obj?.['a']`)
3. Immediately before a function invocation (`obj.a?.()`)

**In the property access position**, if the property value is nullish (ie. `null` or `undefined`), then it immediately short-circuits the entire expression, and returns `undefined`.

**In the function invocation position**, if the function is nullish,  then it immediately short-circuits the entire expression, and returns `undefined` (thereby avoiding an "undefined is not a function" exception).

So:

- `obj.a?.().b` will return `undefined` if `obj.a` is nullish.
- `obj.a()?.b` will return `undefined` if the result of `obj.a().b` is nullish.
- `obj.a?.()?.b` will return `undefined` if `a` is nullish, or if the result of `obj.a()` is nullish.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;TR**

The expression is checked for `non-undefined`, `not-null` values with `?` and at any point if a value is found to be one of these, the chain simply breaks and returns `undefined`.

A very important point to note is it guards **only** against `undefined` and `null` values and not against *falsy* values i.e it will still pass other falsy values like NaN or "".

**Long Explanation**

Let's start with quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional chaining operator provides a way to simplify accessing
> values through connected objects when it's possible that a reference
> or function may be undefined or null.

Consider an object like this:

```
 var obj = {
       a: {
           b: 1
       },
     }
```

Now for validating `obj`, `obj`'s peroperty `a` and then `a`'s property `b` to be not `undefined` and `null`, you may have to do something like this:

```
 obj && obj.a && obj.a.b
```

Optional chaining provides you an alternative to this. You can simply do like this:

```
obj?.a?.b
```

Now, let's say `a` happens to be a function which returns an object with property `b` which holds a value `1`. Something like this:

```
 var obj = {
           a: function{
               return {b:1}
            },
       }
```

So, how will you validate `obj` and its fields now for the deeply nested `b`? Well, you can do something like this:

```
obj && obj.a && typeof obj.a === 'function' && obj.a() && obj.a().b
```

Or you can simply do

```
obj?.a()?.b
```

This just means check `obj` for non-undefined and not-null, (if it is)then check `obj?.a()` for the same, (if it is then)execute the method `a()` of obj. If after the execution the method returns a value (which is not `undefined` or `null`), then get the value of the property `b` from it.

At any point during this *check*, if a value is found to be `undefined` or `null` simply break the chain and return `undefined`

However, this will fail if `a` does not happen to be a function which was checked with `typeof obj.a === 'function'` in the previous expression.
Also, Note that at this point if `obj.a()` happens to return, say, "baz", it will be executed as
`"baz".b` which will give you `undefined`.

With this knowledge,  We can decipher this expression  easily:

```
   obj.a?.().b
```

It checks whether `obj.a` is `non-undefined`, `not-null`. If it is, execute obj.a() (Note that it will throw an error if `obj.a` does not happen to be a function but returns say, number `5`)

If `obj.a()` happens execute successfully then `.b` of the retuned value will be checked.

Now This is left

```
obj.a?.()?.b
```

Well, this also executes like our previous executions:

check `obj.a` if it's  `not-null` and `non-undefined`. If it is,         execute `obj.a`. If that is also `non-null` and `non-undefined`, execute `obj.a()` and so on.

If at any point while checking, value is found to be `null` or `undefined`, the chain simply breaks.

**A very important point to note that our operator `?` guards only against undefined and null not against other *falsy* values .**

Consider this

```js
var a = undefined
var myVal = a?.details.b;
alert(a) //will return undefined

var a = ""
var myVal = a?.details.b;
alert(a) //Our guard fails us here and simply throws an error
```